# mkdir and touch does not work in the same subprocess

Tags: python, bash

import subprocess

```
def execCommand(cmd):
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = proc.communicate()
        return proc.returncode, out, err
    except:
        print "failed"
        return -1, '', ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res, out, error = execCommand(["mkdir", "-p", "/tmp/newdir/", "&&", "touch", "/tmp/newdir/myfile.txt"])
```

The touch command above generates myfile.txt as a directory instead of file, could someone explain why?

Comment: Why don't you use the `os` module? Btw, you can edit your post and don't need to add a comment. Also you could switch to code mode in your post by indentation.

Comment: I guess you need to add `shell=True` to `Popen`

Comment: You either need to add `shell=True` as mentioned or use two subprocesses.

Comment: `&&` is a shell construct.  The way you are calling your command, the OS calls `mkdir` as the command, and everything else as arguments to that command.  You probably will find directories named `&&` and `touch` too resulting from that command.  Others have suggested a way to get your command interpreted by a shell to achieve your purpose which you may want to try.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `subprocess` at all for this. The external commands you are running wrap the same library calls that Python can call itself.

```
import os
os.makedirs("/tmp/newdir")
with open("/tmp/newdir/myfile.txt", "w"):
    pass
```

If you really want a temporary file, consider using the `tempfile` module instead to create the file securely.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained why the op's command did not work.